# Web2py mapping controller to view

Tags: python, model-view-controller, web2py

Just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction here for a web2py app. I have 2 controllers so far but I will be using many more. The 2 I have are `index.py` and `diary_manager.py`.

`index.py` returns an empty dict at the moment and just exposes the `index.html` view in the `myapp/views/index/` directory. Within `index.html` the user can click on a button in the interface with the `href` attribute as follows:

```
<a href="{{=URL(c="diary_manager", f="diary_manager")}}">Diary</a>
```

If I click that link it will call the `diary_manager` function in the `diary_manager.py` controller. All great so far.

Now this is where I encounter an issue. If I return a `dict` from the `diary_manager` function I have to put the corresponding view in the `myapp/views/diary_manager/` directory and this will be exposed. On the other hand, if I don't return a dict I can't expose a view at all.

So I have a few questions:

1. Why do I have to create a directory name matching the controller name in the view when I return a dict?
2. Is there a way to stop this so I can just put all of my views directly into the views directory?
3. How can I force a controller that does not return a dict to open a specific view?

I hope all of that is clear!

Comment: if your function is `diary_manager` then your corresponding view should be `myapp/views/diary_manager` not `myapp/views/diarymanager`

Comment: @JoeR you are indeed correct that was a typo on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why do I have to create a directory name matching the controller name in the view when I return a dict?

You don't have to. It is just a convention so you don't have to explicitly specify where the associated view is for every action. If you don't like that convention, you can put the views wherever you want and name them however you want, but then you have to explicitly specify the view for each action.

> 2. Is there a way to stop this so I can just put all of my views directly into the views directory?

Yes, you can set up your own convention and then include code to set the value of `response.view` according to some rule. For example, suppose you put all view files in the top level `/views` directory and named them using the pattern `[controller]_[function].[extension]`. In that case, in a model file, you could include the following line:

```
response.view = '%s_%s.%s' % (request.controller, request.function,
                              request.extension)
```

If the above code is in a model file, it will be executed on every request, so it will set the view file correctly for every controller/action.

> 3. How can I force a controller that does not return a dict to open a specific view?

Why do you need to do that? If you don't have anything to return but simply want to execute a view, then you can return an empty dictionary.

Alternatively, your function can directly render the view and return the rendered output:

```
def myfunction():
    [some code]
    return response.render()
```

`response.render()` optionally takes a first argument, which is the view file name, and a second argument, which is a dictionary of variables that will be available in the view environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess the whole idea with MVC concept is to make your life easier, as long as you follow some rules.
2. You can set a value of response.view. Also, there is a "redirect".
3. You can't. The view is only called if the action returns a dictionary (as stated in web2py_manual).

Comment: Thanks that all makes sense for sure